# Best way to display a list of items on which the user can take identical actions

Tags: lists, actions, administration

I have a list of entities that are being displayed to a Admin user and the Admin can take a set of actions on any single entity. What is the best way to display those options?

For example, imagine there is a list of users and the Admin can take any of the following actions (a single user at a time):

1. View/edit the user's role (reader, editor, or owner)
2. View the user's profile
3. Delete the user
4. Send an email
5. Generate reset password link

We currently have a table that displays the username in the first column and a link to each of the 5 actions in the next 5 columns, but as the table grows, this looks silly. It's a table of duplicated content where each row is nearly identical to all others. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can **display a simple menu that contains the different actions** when the User element is clicked.

Taking the actions out of scope makes the Admin take an extra step but frees space in the page.

Either a menu or a second page. An example of a [contextual menu](https://material.google.com/components/menus.html#menus-usage):

[image]